# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 3569

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, fetch

I've recently set up a local server with xampp as a testing ground and started making some fetch() tests. I'm trying to fetch a json that's located on the server to try some dynamic DOM creation, but the error keeps popping up.

I've searched for similar problems but i've only found answer for the "Unexpected token <" and i've already have taken care of that. I've also validated the json file just in case.

Here's the js i have.

```js
fetch("./doc/ayuntamientos.json")
  .then(function(resp){
    return resp.json();
  })
  .then(function(data){
    console.log(data.municipios);
  });
```

The json

```
{
  "municipios": [
    {
      "municipio": "Almedíjar",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "Plaza Ayuntamiento, 1",
      "tlf": "964 137 018",
      "mail": "info@almedijar.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Altura",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "Crta. San Vicente, 2",
      "tlf": "964 146 384",
      "mail": "info@altura.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Azuébar",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "C/Excma Diputación, 25",
      "tlf": "964 650 006",
      "mail": "info@azuebar.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Bejís",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "C/Virgen del Loreto, 2",
      "tlf": "964 120 161",
      "mail": "info@bejis.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Benafer",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "Plaza Nueva, 1",
      "tlf": "964 764 111",
      "mail": "info@benafer.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Castellnovo",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "Plaza Ayuntamiento, 2",
      "tlf": "964 137 305",
      "mail": "info@castellnovo.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Caudiel",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "Plaza España, 1",
      "tlf": "964 144 049",
      "mail": "info@caudiel.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Chóvar",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "Plaza Iglesia, 1",
      "tlf": "964 651 024",
      "mail": "info@chovar.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "El Toro",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "Plaza Iglesia, 1",
      "tlf": "964 123 001",
      "mail": "info@eltoro.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Fuente la Reina",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "C/Barcelona",
      "tlf": "964 145 701",
      "mail": "info@fuentelareina.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Geldo",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "Plaza D.Antonio Ferriz Díaz, 4",
      "tlf": "964 711 209",
      "mail": "info@geldo.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Jérica",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "C/Historiador Vayo,19",
      "tlf": "964 129 177",
      "mail": "ayuntamiento@jerica.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Navajas",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "C/De Valencia, 7",
      "tlf": "964 710 801",
      "mail": "ayuntamiento@navajas.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Pina de Montalgrao",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "Pina Ayuntamiento, 1",
      "tlf": "964 121 031",
      "mail": "info@pinademontalgrao.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Soneja",
      "sitio": "Mancomunidad Alto Palancia",
      "direccion": "C/Alto Palancia, 4",
      "tlf": "964 132 740",
      "mail": "info@altopalancia.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Sot de Ferrer",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "Palancia España, 1",
      "tlf": "964 135 127",
      "mail": "info@sotdeferrer.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Teresa",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "C/Montoliu, 2",
      "tlf": "964 141 192",
      "mail": "info@teresa.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Torás",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "Palancia Iglesia, 1",
      "tlf": "964 120 238",
      "mail": "info@toras.es"
    },
    {
      "municipio": "Viver",
      "sitio": "Ayuntamiento",
      "direccion": "Palancia Mayor del Palancia, 1 ",
      "tlf": "964 141 006",
      "mail": "info@viver.es"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm just confused and in need of some guidance. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you validate the entire JSON structure?  It looks like you have an unbalanced array close bracket, like a `]` without a matching `[`.

Comment: I strongly suspect we'll need the entire JSON. The error you've given suggests that there is an out-of-place `]` character (compare `JSON.parse("{]")` for the same error), but the small sample you give contains no such error.

Comment: I added the full json, thanks for the help.

Comment: JSONLint says what you posted here is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy, and kind of upset of my ignorance, to say that I have solved the issue. Plainly, I didn't start the FileZilla module on Xampp. Thanks for all the help.